# Perl syntax error: Bareword found where operator expected

Tags: perl

As the title suggests how could I accomplish this?

I have been following a tutorial, but I get a syntax error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at arrays_and_variables.pl line
26, near "$2names"
        (Missing operator before names?) syntax error at
arrays_and_variables.pl line 26, near "$2names " Execution of
arrays_and_variables.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The code I have so far is:

```
@names = ('james','dylan','max');

# join elements of array into a schalar variable.
$2names = join ('', @names);
print $s2names;
```

Comment: use strict; use warnings; at the top of your program would help catch this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2names` is an invalid variable name. Names can't start with a number—they have to begin with a letter or an underscore.

Comment: Ahh! I see, the code looked fine to me :D, knew it was something simple :P Thanks

Comment: @Ben: Glad to help. Would you mind if I changed the title of your post to something like "Perl syntax error: Bareword found where operator expected" so it's more easily searchable for people who have the same problem in the future?